# What node would allow me to edit the mapping coordinates individually?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I'm making a procedural texture, and I want to expose the following values so that they are controlled by a separate node.

[image]

I'm using the Cycles material node editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **Separate XYZ** node. (add>Converter>Separate XYZ)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the Scale values from the Mapping node, it is simpler to use the MixRGB. Just plug the vector in the input A, use the CombineXYZ for input B with your [scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ] values, operation to 'Multiply' and the factor to 1.

Comment: Suggested watching: Bartek Skorupa's Video: [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0)